# How to construct an object from data packed in a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, tuples, variadic-templates

Suppose I have

```
struct SomeType {
  template<typename... Args>
  SomeType(Args... args);
  // ...
};

template<typename... Args> std::tuple<Args> data;   // syntax correct?
```

and want to construct a new object `SomeType` from the argument values packed in the `tuple` `data`. How can I do that?

```
unique_ptr<SomeType> p = new SomeType( data ??? );  // how?
```

---

**edit 1** I thought the question was pretty clear, but Kevin disagrees ... I want call the constructor of `SomeBody` with the values packed in the `tuple` `data` as arguments. Got it, Keven?

---

**edit 2** I thought a question is a question, but Kevin disagrees again. For his benefit, here is a use case: I want to dynamically construct thread-local objects, each constructed by its thread from some arguments provided earlier. Consider

```
template<typename Object>
class thread_specific
{
public:
  // default constructor: objects will be default constructed
  thread_specific();
  // objects will be copy constructed from specimen provided
  thread_specific(Object const&specimen);
  // objects will be constructed from arguments provided
  template<typename... Args>
  thread_specifiv(Args... args);
  // return thread-specific object; objects are constructed only when needed
  Object& local_object();
};
```

(implemented, say, via a `std::map<std::thread::id,unique_ptr<Object>>`). Now, if a global `thread_specific<>` object is created by the user using the 3rd constructor, the arguments must be stored somehow and fed to the constructor of `Object` when needed, i.e. at the first call to `thread_specific<>::local_object()` on each `std::thread`.